# Spring Security Without Role-Base Using Database

Tags: database, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I want to implement Spring Security(Authentication and Authorisation) I Google about it and any [MKYoung Spring Security Example](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/), I Just want to distinguish URLs between authenticated user and Anonymous user, I don't want to use any Role-Base Authorisation.

Any Users who are registered and logged in, i want to authorise them for all URLs and for anonymous users i want them for Login and Registration page.
Thanks

Comment: What is the question? You don't have to use role based access control in Spring (search for `isAuthenticated()` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` within Spring reference manual).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, going to try it.

Comment: Nice... check Jean-Philippe's answer... I was too lazy to write an actual answer like he did :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to do it in the spring security xml configuration file :

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/registration" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
     ...
</security:http>
```

Comment: No i will try it, here i have another confusion MKYoung refering data source using <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"> but for my case i am using <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> for my hibernate

Comment: Post another question for the data source, I will respond with an example.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by using query:

```
authorities-by-username-query="select username, 'default' from users where username=?"
```